# How to copy object

Tags: typescript

I'm writing an application in typescript and I'm trying to strongly type `Object.assign` call like this:

```
let obj = new Author();
let x = Object.assign({}, obj);
```

I want variable `x` to be of type `Author`. Unfortunately it is of type `Object`.

If I do something like this, I get a proper type:

```
Object.assign<Author, Author>(new Author(), obj);
```

I can even simplify first type argument:

```
Object.assign<{}, Author>(new Author(), obj);
```

This is, however, quite verbose (I need to specify types by hand) and forces me to create an `Author` object before assigning. Is there any other way to achieve this? Or is there any other way of copying an object in typescript while preserving its prototype?

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using? I've just tried your code and it seems like `x` is of type `{} & Author`

Comment: I'm using typescript 2.3.2. Maybe my question was not accurate enough. Imagine there is a method `someMethod` in `Author` object. If I try to call `x.someMethod()` I'm getting an error: `x.someMethod` is not a function. Also, `temp instanceof Author` returns false.

Answer (score 3):

you mean something like this? maybe I missunderstood your question, but like this, you would combine the types/values quit nicely

```
let test = {name: "value"};
let item = {hallo: "hallo", ...test};
```

also something like this is working

```
// could be also defined as class
type Author = {name: string, value: string}

let authorValue = {value: "value"}
let authorName = {name: "name"}

let author: Author = {...authorName, ...authorValue};
```

of course instanceof will not work as those types will not be transpiled.

Here some more test

```
class Author {
    constructor(public name, public value) {}
}
let authorName = {name: "name"}
let author = new Author("Franz", "Value");
let combined: Author = { ...author, ...authorName }
// false
console.log(combined instanceof Author);
Object.assign(author, authorName);
// true
console.log(author instanceof Author);
```

Comment: what if `Author` is a class and I'd like to be able to call its method on a result object?

Comment: check out the transpiled code https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Author%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20authorValue%20%3D%20%7Bvalue%3A%20%22value%22%7D%0D%0Alet%20authorName%20%3D%20%7Bname%3A%20%22name%22%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20author%3A%20Author%20%3D%20%7B...authorValue%2C%20...authorName%7D

Comment: After further investigation I come to a conclusion that there is a deeper problem here. The actual type is correct I think - after doing this: `let x = Object.assign({}, obj);` I can assign `x` to a variable of type `Author`  (`let f:  Author = x;` works as expected). The problem is, that neither `x` nor `f` have a prototype of `Author` class, so I can't call any methods from `Author` on them.

Comment: That is not true if you follow my example and assign as shown. You must use the Author value as the first arg in Object.assign. Otherwise you only copy properties of Author into an empty object.

Comment: yes, if I pass `Author` as a first argument it works. Turns out Object.assign is used to _copy the values of all **enumerable own** properties from one or more source objects to a target object_ [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign]. Result is a first argument with properties copied from second argument. It will have a prototype of whatever was passed first. I guess I have no choice but to use `Object.assign(new Author(), obj);`.